# Is there a way to have netcat listen and place incoming files in a destination directory?

Tags: networking, file-transfer, netcat

I'd like to use netcat to regularly transfer files to a media server on my network. However, I can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to do something like `nc -l 5959 > /media/data/`, where incoming nc data is just stored in the destination directory as whatever file the sender named it.

Is this possible?
I don't mind using scp, but it's painfully slow for large amounts of data..

Comment: Not without more logic on the receiving side, as the sender's file name is gone by the time the listening netcat gets the data.

Answer (score 3):

On the receiving side:

```
nc -l -p 5959 | ( cd /media/data; cpio -idmv )
```

On the sending side:

```
find /some/dir -type f -print | cpio -oa | nc machine 5959
```

However, you really should consider using `scp` instead:

```
cd /some/dir
scp -r . user@machine:/media/data
```